# How to fix this error: Template Does Not Exist?

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('',views.home, name='home')
    
]
```

another urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('subokLang.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

settings.py - templates

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'tryingDjango/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/home.html')
```

I am stuck here, tried changing many already, still won't work, the 500(Template does not exist), what is the right code?

Comment: Please convert this into code by using command ctrl+k

Comment: it's been along time i am not using django. but you can try this : 'DIRS': ['templates'], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file:

inside TEMPLATES, just add this:

```
[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

**Ex:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], #Added here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I tried this one, and got this,
I've imported os too
\projects\tryingDjango\subokLang\views.py, line 7, in home
    return render(request, 'templates/home.html') …
Local vars
Variable Value
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/'>

I still got the same error.

Comment: instead of this (request, 'templates/home.html')  render this (request, 'home.html'). just remove templates from render in views